# Determine if WhoId is for lead in formula field

Tags: formula

I created a number formula field that looks at the WhoId of the activity and the goal was to determine if the value was a lead or a contact so that I can do reporting on it.

This is the formula I am using, but leads are still failing the logic test. Can anyone offer some insight as to what I may be forgetting in my logic?

Thanks for your time,

IF(WhoId = LEFT("00Q",3), 1, 0)

Comment: What is your end goal here? Seems likely you could do away with this formula entirely.

Answer (score 3):

You can just check `Who.Type`, which is much more clear syntactically.

If your field is `Is_Lead__c`:

```
Who.Type = "Lead"
```

If your field is `Who_Type__c`:

```
Who.Type
```

Note that in queries, you could even just pull `Who.Type` directly, with no need for a formula. But you might need to build it out for certain types of reporting. Since you haven't made your end goal clear in the question, I included the latter formula as well.

Comment: +1 , Far better and cleaner, no hardcoding Id's .

Comment: I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but `Who.Type` doesn't actually compile as a formula field value. It seems to work pretty much everywhere else *except* for this one use case.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use LEFT on WhoID and then check(==) with 00Q to see if its lead or not.

```
IF(LEFT(WhoId,3)=='00Q', 1, 0)
```

Better way would be to use switch case

```
Case(LEFT(WhoId , 3),'00Q','Lead','003','Contact','Other' )
```

Comment: Awesome! That did the trick! Can you help me understand the "==" instead of using an = in the first scenario that you have? Or is it the same?

Comment: The = and == operator are interchangeable. So same thing